# Get cell value in Excel VBA user definited function returns "#VALUE!" when Dim is used

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to get the value of a cell that's left to the calling cell of a user defined function in Excel.

This works:

```vb
Public Function DisplayCaller() As String
    Application.Volatile
    Row = Application.Caller.Row
    Column = Application.Caller.Column
    DisplayCaller = Cells(Row, Column - 1).Value2
End Function
```

This returns "#VALUE!"

```vb
Public Function DisplayCaller() As String
    Application.Volatile
    Row = Application.Caller.Row
    Column = Application.Caller.Column
    Dim x As Range
    x = Cells(Row, Column - 1)
    DisplayCaller = x.Value2
End Function
```

I also get "#VALUE!" if I do this:

```vb
Public Function DisplayCaller() As String
    Application.Volatile
    Dim r as Range
    r = Application.Caller
    Row =  r.Row
    Column = r.Column
    DisplayCaller = Cells(Row, Column - 1).Value2
End Function
```

Whenever I'm using `Dim` the result is "#VALUE!" - why?

Comment: You need to use Set with a Range object.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick. It's been a while since I've been using VBA...

Comment: Excel's calc engine is swallowing errors here; you can debug a UDF more easily if you invoke it from VBA code or the immediate toolwindow rather than from a worksheet cell.

Comment: FWIW Rubberduck would have flagged it as a [suspicious Let assignment](https://test.rubberduckvba.com/FeatureDetails?name=SuspiciousLetAssignment)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon how can I test a UDF from a VBA Sub if it is evaluating the `Application.Caller`?

Comment: lol yeah that's... what happens when one doesn't _quite_ read the actual code  I only looked at the assignment, completely overlooked the rest

Comment: I was already thinking about to pass a reference to the calling cell from the VBA Sub for testing/debugging purposes and explicitely expecting a range parameter in the UDF during debugging - could this work? Failed somehow...

Comment: No, `Application.Caller` is doing some weird stuff, IIRC it returns `Nothing` if it's another procedure calling it.

Comment: You could debug the functions by simply setting a breakpoint and stepping through. Not ideal and the code will stop as soon as you get an error but it will *kind* of work.